# Split or join lines in Linux using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, tr

I have file that contains below information

```
$ cat test.txt 
Studentename:Ram
rollno:12
subjects:6
Highest:95
Lowest:65
Studentename:Krish
rollno:13
subjects:6
Highest:90
Lowest:45
Studentename:Sam
rollno:14
subjects:6
Highest:75
Lowest:65
```

I am trying place info of single student in single. 
i.e My output should be

```
Studentename:Ram rollno:12 subjects:6 Highest:95 Lowest:65
Studentename:Krish rollno:13 subjects:6 Highest:90 Lowest:45
Studentename:Sam rollno:14 subjects:6 Highest:75 Lowest:65.
```

Below is the command I wrote

```
cat test.txt | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/Lowest:[0-9]\+/Lowest:[0:9]\n/g'
```

Above command is breaking line at regex Lowest:[0-9] but it doesn't print the pattern. Instead it is printing Lowest:[0-9].

Please help

Comment: Does the input file looks exactly like this with the blank lines like this ???

Comment: @GillesQuenot I just eliminated the blank lines because, in my experience, it takes a while for people new to SO to discover the code formatting button: `{}`.  If I guessed wrong, I hope the OP will promptly correct me.

Comment: Basically file does contain  blank lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed '/^Studente/{:a; N; /Lowest/!ba; s/\n/ /g}' test.txt
Studentename:Ram rollno:12 subjects:6 Highest:95 Lowest:65
Studentename:Krish rollno:13 subjects:6 Highest:90 Lowest:45
Studentename:Sam rollno:14 subjects:6 Highest:75 Lowest:65
```

#### How it works

`/^Studente/{...}` tells sed to perform the commands inside the curly braces only on lines that start with `Studente`.  Those commands are:

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `N`

  This reads in the next line and appends it to the pattern space.
- `/Lowest/!ba`

  If the current pattern space does not contain `Lowest`, this tells sed to branch back to label `a`.

  In more detail, `/Lowest/` is true if the line contains `Lowest`.  In sed, `!` is negation so `/Lowest/! is true if the line does not contain`Lowest`.  In`ba`, the`b`stands for the branch command and`a` is the label to branch to.
- `s/\n/ /g`

  This tells sed to replace all newlines with spaces.

Comment: When it comes to do conditional expressions, awk is more readable :)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: Be careful of false positives. My name is `Lowest`

Answer (score 2):

Try this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '{if ($1 !~ /^Lowest/) {printf "%s ", $0} else {print}}' file.txt
```

Or shorter but more obfuscated :

```
awk '$1!~/^Lowest/{printf"%s ",$0;next}1' file.txt
```

Or correcting your command :

```
tr "\n" " " < file.txt | sed 's/Lowest:[0-9]\+/&\n/g'
```

Explanation: `&` is whats matched in the left part of substitution

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I missed "&". Thank you so much

Comment: Since your answer works nicely and also because the anonymous downvoter left no reason for his downvotes: +1.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) that doesn't assume **Lowest** is the last item:

```
sed ':a; N; /\nStudent/{P; D}; s/\n/ /; ba' test.txt
```

Comment: You get a +1 from me because your answer is creative and it works and doesn't deserve a net negative score due to some anonymous downvoter who didn't leave a message on any of our answers.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Studentename:/{:a;x;s/\n/ /gp;d};H;$ba;d' file
```

Use the hold space to gather up the fields and then remove the newlines to produce a record.